# Log4J log on year folder

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to store log4j logs in a folder by year.
For example:

```
log4j.appender.File=${log.app.path}/${currentYear}/application.log
```

But how to set ${currentYear}?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this way.

```
System.setProperty("currentYear", YOUR YEAR VALUE);
```

Comment: Is there any log4J Append for this purpose?

Comment: @tobia no there. but you can harcode your value.



log4j.appender.File=${log.app.path}/2013/application.log

Comment: Yes, but I need to runtime reconfig log4 (before it was only configured by log4j.properties).

Comment: this configuration done run time only 
put this set of line at beginning of your code.